# Android / C++ - The command ""\bin\ant.bat" exited with code 3

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio

I've been looking around everywhere and it seems no one gets my errorcode, I've gone through a lot installing Apache Ant, setting up ANT_HOME (Which Visual Studio says ANT_HOME is empty) but anyways. This is my error when trying to compile a Native Activity Application for Android C++

```
Error MSB3073   The command ""\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="c:\users\trevin\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Android1\Android1\Android1.Packaging\x86\Debug\Android1.apk"" exited with code 3. Android1.Packaging  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets    378
```

This is my output log:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
ANT_HOME=
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
java.home=
NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r10e\
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r10e\
The system cannot find the path specified.
*Errorcode from above*
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a good 2 weeks now doing research constantly but I can't find anyone else with this error code or where to even search to how to fix it so I decided to ask.

Comment: Ant has been deprecated as an Android build system for ~2 years, unless Microsoft is doing their own thing with it.

Comment: It may not be required I just seen other "error-codes" people have reported need Ant etc, so if it is deprecated hopefully it isn't a requirement lol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Ant path in Tools->Options->Cross Platform->C++->Android
That fixed the error for me